# .NET OAuth Google API

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to implement OAuth Google API, but did not find any elegnat example to start with. Somehow, I statred with http://dotnetopenauth.net/

I created a single page named "Login.aspx" which contain the code

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GoogleOAuth
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
            var response = openid.GetResponse();
            //Checks whether user is authenticated or not
            if (response != null && response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated && response.Provider.Uri == new Uri("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud"))
            {
                var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                string email = String.Empty;
                if (fetch != null)
                {
                    email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email); //Fetching requested emailid
                }

            }
        }
        protected void GoogleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
            {
                var request = openid.CreateRequest("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id");
                var fetch = new FetchRequest();
                fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email); // Request for email id
                request.AddExtension(fetch); // Adding in request obj
                request.RedirectToProvider();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On this page, it works fine. After ogin the above code return the email address. But what I am wondering to transfer the user after he logged in and fetch data on a different page instead on the same page. How it is possible?

If I copied the code which is inside Page_Load, and paste into other page it does not work. That return null in response.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I recomend that you start by using C# using Google.Apis.v3.  Depending upon which api you are trying to access things will be slightly diffrent.

```
UserCredential credential; 
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
          new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
          "user",
          CancellationToken.None,
          new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result; }
```

Thats an Oauth example that will connect to Google Drive.  From the looks of your code you are trying to access google+ so the Scopes will be diffrent.

You can find a basic tutorial to get you started with Google Oath2 here:  [Google OAuth2 C#](http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/?rel=nofollow)

Comment: Thank you! I was going nuts not finding any examples in Google's documentation.